# How to say browser to start download file?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

Using client side I do POST request to Laravel to get back file to browser:

```
$headers = [
             'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
             'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename='Report.xls'"
        ];

        return response()->download(storage_path('app/'.$path.$filename), $filename, $headers);
```

**It returns me binary file in response:**

[image]

**Response headers are:**

[image]

Comment: i think you will need to use `return response()->file()` instead of `response()->download()`

Comment: I tried, it gives me the same result

Comment: maybe you need to pass the Content-Size header?

Comment: I tried, no result, it always back me binary file in response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```php
return Storage::download('file.jpg', $name, $headers);
```

**Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#downloading-files**

**EDIT 1:**

***Possible solution:***

Create a route for getting a xls document (with the GET http method) by his name for example who returns:

```php
return Storage::download('file.jpg', $name, $headers);
```

Do a POST request, return the `204` http code and with the `Location` header.

```php
return response()->header('Location', $url)
```

When the AJAX success event is called do:

```js
success: function(data, textStatus, request) {
    window.open(request.getResponseHeader('Location'), '_blank');
}
```

Comment: The same result, maybe problem in POST request?

Comment: @OPV i think (if it is an ajax call) you will be better to open a new tab on your browser

Comment: I tried to open in new tab full path to file, no result

Comment: And why do you perform a POST request?

Comment: Sure, it returns me also binary content

Comment: Cause I need send ids rows that I need to fill in Excel file

Comment: Now I get full path to file as: `C:\Projects\events\Backend\storage\app/events/1.xls`

Comment: And try to open it in new tab: `window.open(res.file);`

Comment: i think you can just do a `<form method="post">` who open a new tab, without an AJAX call

Comment: Can you show an sample? Now it opens blank window by full path

Comment: If pass this path to URL browser it starts to download file: `C:\Projects\events\Backend\storage\app/events/1.xls`

Comment: i have made an edit, i think you need to separate your creation of your file and the download